# firebase database value of total

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

what kind of approaches needed to add the total amount of qty value in firebase?
here i attached firebase databse screenshot.

[image: Firebase database screenshot]

supposedly, the sum of qty from list and second would be 500+800=1300. so i would expected to get that total sum 1300. below is the code for retrieving data from firebase to be stored on textview (@+id/txt_total_value) for display.

```
mUploads = new ArrayList<>();

    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Sreeauto");

    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int sum = 0;

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot dSnapshot : postSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Datastore upload = dSnapshot.getValue(Datastore.class);
                    mUploads.add(upload);

                    int value = 
Integer.parseInt(dSnapshot.child("qty").getValue(String.class));
                    sum += value;


                }

            }

            mAdapter = new Adapater(ViewProduction.this, mUploads);

            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mprogress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            txt_total_value.setText(sum);

        }
```

**Datastore.java**

```
public class Datastore {

private String Date;
private String Shift;
private String Qty;
private String Incharge;

public Datastore(){

}

public Datastore(String date,String shift, String qty, String incharge){
    Date = date;
    Shift = shift;
    Qty = qty;
    Incharge = incharge;
}

public String getDate() {
    return Date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    Date = date;
}

public String getShift() {
    return Shift;
}

public void setShift(String shift) {
    Shift = shift;
}

public String getQty() {
    return Qty;
}

public void setQty(String qty) {
    Qty = qty;
}

public String getIncharge() {
    return Incharge;
}

public void setIncharge(String incharge) {
    Incharge = incharge;
}
}
```

**ViewProduction.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.udayaj.sreeauto.ViewProduction">



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:text="Date"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/incharge"
    android:text="Shift"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:text="Qty"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/incharge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
    android:text="Incharge"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/incharge"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerji">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_total"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/txt_total_value"
    android:text="Total : "
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_total_value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="00000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

An example would be a helpful. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You already seem to be looping over your data, so all that is still needed is extracting the value and adding them together:

```
mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for (DataSnapshot dSnapshot : postSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Datastore upload = dSnapshot.getValue(Datastore.class);
                mUploads.add(upload);

                int value = Integer.parseInt(dSnapshot.child("qty").getValue(String.class));
                sum += value;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

You might already have `qty` in your `Datastore` class. But since you didn't share that code, the above doesn't rely on that.

Consider storing the value of `qty` as a number. That would make the `Integer.parseInt` unnecessary and reduce the chance of problems.

Comment: i added Datastore.java. please give me correct example. i got a error in the line System.out.println(sum);

Comment: logcat: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(int)' on a null object reference                                         at com.udayaj.sreeauto.ViewProduction$1.onDataChange(ViewProduction.java:82)

Comment: @AndréKool waiting for your reply

Comment: @user9879624 That error looks completely unrelated to the code in your question. Please update your question with the relevant code, what you have tried (this answer) and what failed. You can use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50667535/edit) button below your question to include the information.

Comment: @AndréKool i added . i need to show total value on txt_total_value text view. please give me some example. urgent.

Comment: @user9879624 Please edit your question, not this answer.

Comment: I need example for firebase child database total value to show on textview. No One should not given right example .

Comment: @Frankvanpuffelen I need your help. Please give me correct example.

Comment: My code shows how to calculate the sum on your database nodes. If there is a problem with that code let me know. The error message you showed in comments seems caused because `txt_total_value` is not initialized. It's impossible for us to say why that is with the information you shared.